# Why add a small number on the bounding box?

Tags: computer-vision, object-detection

I found that on the implementation of Fast(er) RCNN, there is always a small value added to the width and height of the bounding box. Why add a small number to the width and height?

For example, in [Fast RCNN](https://github.com/rbgirshick/fast-rcnn/blob/b612190f279da3c11dd8b1396dd5e72779f8e463/lib/roi_data_layer/roidb.py#L104), `cfg.EPS` ([default](https://github.com/rbgirshick/fast-rcnn/blob/b612190f279da3c11dd8b1396dd5e72779f8e463/lib/fast_rcnn/config.py#L125) is `1e-14`) is added:

```py
ex_widths = ex_rois[:, 2] - ex_rois[:, 0] + cfg.EPS
ex_heights = ex_rois[:, 3] - ex_rois[:, 1] + cfg.EPS
ex_ctr_x = ex_rois[:, 0] + 0.5 * ex_widths
ex_ctr_y = ex_rois[:, 1] + 0.5 * ex_heights

gt_widths = gt_rois[:, 2] - gt_rois[:, 0] + cfg.EPS
gt_heights = gt_rois[:, 3] - gt_rois[:, 1] + cfg.EPS
gt_ctr_x = gt_rois[:, 0] + 0.5 * gt_widths
gt_ctr_y = gt_rois[:, 1] + 0.5 * gt_heights
```

In [Faster-RCNN](https://github.com/rbgirshick/py-faster-rcnn/blob/781a917b378dbfdedb45b6a56189a31982da1b43/lib/fast_rcnn/bbox_transform.py#L11), `1.0` is added to `widths` and `heights`.

```py
ex_widths = ex_rois[:, 2] - ex_rois[:, 0] + 1.0
ex_heights = ex_rois[:, 3] - ex_rois[:, 1] + 1.0
ex_ctr_x = ex_rois[:, 0] + 0.5 * ex_widths
ex_ctr_y = ex_rois[:, 1] + 0.5 * ex_heights

gt_widths = gt_rois[:, 2] - gt_rois[:, 0] + 1.0
gt_heights = gt_rois[:, 3] - gt_rois[:, 1] + 1.0
gt_ctr_x = gt_rois[:, 0] + 0.5 * gt_widths
gt_ctr_y = gt_rois[:, 1] + 0.5 * gt_heights
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don’t know what is happening in the first case, but in the second case looks like the left and right locations are both inside the bounding box. The number of pixels spanned must therefore include both left and right locations. This is why 1 is added.

Answer (score 0):

I have a strong feeling the code will continue with the areas of the boxes and use those for calculating the IoU. If so, you need to be sure the bounding box actually has some non-zero area.

Answer (score 0):

My opinion.Actually,The pixels on the "bounding box border" are need to be calculated.SO you need to exclude them(by add 1).